# instead of wp-login.php how to display login error in a custom wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

Am using wordpress login in a popup. But after failed login or user not verified email before login, its redirecting to wp-login.php and showing error message. I need to show in a custom page which is including my template for to show this error message.I already checked different forum and add code in theme functions.php, but its not worked.

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );
// hook failed login

function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {

$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// where did the post submission come from? // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen

if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {

wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );

// let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use

exit; } }
```